# extJS 4.2 Newbie Q - Loop through Store or Grid

Tags: arrays, loops, store, extjs4.2

UPDATED: I answered my own question.  It may be and idiots solution but then again I am not convinced the frame work is idiot proof.  My problem was that I could not get the load event to fire for my store.  I added the following lines after the init function but before this.control function:

```
    init: function() {

    Ext.getStore('Users').addListener('load',this.onUsersStoreLoad, this);

    Ext.getStore('Users').addListener('datachanged',this. onUsersStoreDataChange, this);

    this.control(
    {


        'viewport > userlist':
        {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser,
        },


        'useredit button[action=save]':
        {
            click: this.updateUser
        }           


    });



},

onUsersStoreLoad: function(me,records,success)
{

// Do something ignorant with your code here
};
```

This works for a paged grid/store or whatever.  Please feel free to make suggestion on how to improve this if this is a bad way to approach the load event for my store.

Thanks,
UPDATE END:

I can not for the love of god/country figure how to loop through a store or grid.  I am newbie and while I think it would better to loop through the store opposed to a grid I can seem to find a way to do either.  I have read several posts where folks seemingly have the same issue and have found a solution.  However, when I try to implement the solution i get an undefined error when loging to console.  Clearly my understanding is sub par as I am unable to determine if i am putting my code in the proper places.

I have used this link in SO as a model of what I want to do and I can't get it to work:

```
http:/stackoverflow.com/questions/3149107/how-to-loop-through-the-extjs-grid-object-to-get-its-elements-and-values
```

I want to disable dates in my date picker with an array.  It works when I hard code it but what I really want to do is load the dateArray dynamically with the unix_time_stamp coloumn of my grid provided by my users store.  I have tried stub in message boxes everywhere I can possibly do it and I can not seem to get it to fire so that tells me i am fundamentally screwed up.  Please help.

View:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.userlist',
title: 'All Users',
store: 'Users',
plugins:[Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {clicksToEdit: 1})],
dockedItems: [{ xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'Users',
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayMsg: 'Displaying Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                displayInfo: true}],


initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [
                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer',
                        {
                        resizable: true,
                        resizeHandles:'all',
                        align: 'center',
                        minWidth: 35,
                        maxWidth:50
                        }),
                    {
                    header: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'message_id',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'recip_email',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Date Time',
                    dataIndex: 'unix_time_stamp',
                    width: 120,
                    menuDisabled:true,
                    // submitFormat: 'd/m/Y',
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                    field:{ xtype:'datefield',
                            autoSync:true,
                            allowBlank:false,
                            editor: new Ext.form.DateField(
                                    {format: 'm/d/y'})  }
                    }];



    this.callParent(arguments);


},
```

});

Store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync:true,
pageSize:50,
proxy:
{
    type: 'ajax',
    api:
    {
        read: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2.cfc?method=getContent',
        update: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2-post.cfc?method=postContent'

    },
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success',
        totalProperty : 'dataset',
        remoteFilter : true
    },
    listeners:
    {
        // stuff goes here
    }
}
```

});

Viewport:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

// This array is for testing.
dateArray = ["12/14/2013","12/16/2013","12/18/2013","12/20/2013"];

// var disabledDates = [];
// var usersStore = Ext.getStore('User');
// console.log(usersStore);
// usersStore.store.each(function(record){
//  disabledDates.push(record.get(unix_time_stamp));
// });
```

Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Users'],

```
launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

    layout: 'border',

     items:
        [
            {

            region: 'center',
            //layout:'fit',
            title:'The Title',
            xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
            activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
            items:
            [{
                xtype: 'userlist',
                listeners:
                {
                    select: function(selModel, record, index, options)
                    {
                        // do something with the selected date
                        // Ext.Msg.alert(record.data.message_id, record.data.recip_email +'<br> ' + record.data.unix_time_stamp);
                    }
                }
            }]

            },
            {
            region: 'west',
            layout:'fit',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activetab:0,
            collapsible:false,
            split: false,
            title: 'The Title',

            width:178,
            maxWidth:400,
            height: 100,
            minHeight: 100,
            items:
            [
            {
                title: 'Tab 1',
                xtype:'panel',
                items:
                    [{
                    xtype: 'datepicker',
                    minDate: new Date('12/15/2013'),
                    maxDate: new Date(),
                    // Disable dates is set to invert dates in array
                    // disabledDates:["^(?!"+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],
                    disabledDates:["^("+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],

                    handler: function(picker, date)
                            {

                            // do something with the selected date
                            // Ext.Msg.alert('date picker example in init2.js' + '<br>' + Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                            console.log('date picker example in init2.js' + Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                            // get store by unique storeId
                            var store = Ext.getStore('Users');

                            // clear current filters
                             store.clearFilter(true);

                            // filter store
                            Ext.encode(store.filter("unix_time_stamp", Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y')));

                            // store.proxy.extraParams = { key:'test'};
                            store.load();
                            // store.sync();

                            }
                    }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'ers may be added dynamically  - Others may be added dynamically',
            }

            ]

            }
        ]

    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the store function each()

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each